# design patterns, help find best approach

Tags: c#, class, oop, design-patterns

There is a class Task, that has its methods and properties.  It is an entity in my project. A Task is just like a regular daily task, that has its date, its title, body (actual task) and status completed/not completed as well as setters and getters for described properties above.

One could add a new task, or remove a task. Filter tasks based on its properties, sort them, etc. These operations are related to a list of elements of type Task. Question: Should there be a separate class for the list of tasks and its corresponding methods related to the list? If so, what should be the relationship between Task class and TaskList class? Any design pattern or a specific approach you could recommend?

Comment: I'd add a ToDoList abstraction with the methods you described.  It's good to exploit abstract data types and encapsulation.  That's what OO is all about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your task list doesn't do anything more than a regular list, then IMHO you can just create a `List<Task>`.

If you want to do something special to the list, say, marking all the tasks as completed, then you can probably encapsulate a `List<Task>` in a class called `TaskList`. Something like this:

```
public class TaskList : List<Task> {
    // extra methods and stuff
}
```

You asked what should be the relationship between the task and the task list. Well, there you go, you can use inheritance just like this above. Alternatively, you can store a private instance of `List<Task>` in the class like this:

```
public class TaskList : IEnumerable {
    private List<Task> innerList;
}
```

But then you have to implement a lot more methods like `Add`, `Remove`, `GetEnumerator` etc. I'm kind of lazy so I would stick with the first method.

Comment: Thanks. I'll follow your advice. Very helpful.

Comment: Lazy programmers are good programmers.

Answer (score 2):

While I can add almost nothing to @Sweeper's comment, perhaps a useful question when asking "should I create a new class?" is "Does this potential object both know things AND do things (e.g. have both data AND methods)?"

In your example, possible TaskList methods might be `CompleteAll` or `Share`. If you're going to implement those, Make a `TaskList` class. If not, use `List<Task>`. Better yet, Make all of your methods that deal with collections depend on `IEnumerable<Task>` or `ICollection<Task>` -- build your first version with a `List<Task>` and refactor later to pass a TaskList along that inherits from List as Sweeper suggests.

I think the reason you're getting downvotes is this question properly belongs in Programmers, not SO. SO is for solving specific problems, Programmers is more open-ended, so questions like yours belong there. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/